# How do I paraphrase a table?

Tags: research-process, thesis, writing

I have to add a table to my thesis but it is detected as plagiarism. I have used data from this table in my thesis.

However I wish to prevent this table to be detected by Turnitin. Is there any way I can paraphrase my table without changing its contents?

Comment: Why is it detected? Is it a false positive or did you plagiarize?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, and you are using Turnitin wrong. The question you should be asking is how you can properly include that table.

Comment: It is not plagiarism. This is a table from own research paper. This I want to put into my thesis but dont want it to be included in similarity check.

Answer (score 3):

Tables can typically be included verbatim (under fair use), just cite your source.

Turnitin is presumably just detecting verbatim inclusion. Assuming you've correctly cited your source, you can ignore.